# Error unmounting Docker - invalid argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

Currently using AWS EC2 with Docker 1.10.3 installed.

After running up a container with Nginx inside, if I reboot my machine it fails to bring back up the container with the error:

```
msg="devmapper: Error unmounting device a066c3d476c9201aa8cfeefced4d7d7c4c05096165aec35a06d3585abd1d3a09: invalid argument"
```

I can get it to work if I delete the contents of /var/lib/docker/*, however, is there a more elegant way to resolve this? What could be the cause?

Comment: So if you delete /var/lib/docker/* and reboot, your container can then be started? I presume you lose all your images, past containers, named volumes, and then have to pull down your images again. Since you've removed the previous install, have you considered switching over your storage driver to aufs? You're also a few versions back and may want to upgrade.

Comment: That's right I pull down my images again then it works fine. I have tried switching to AUFS but my OS kernel doesn't support it (CentOS 7). However, I tried Overlay and that seems to fix the problem strangely enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution - move to Overlay storage driver. The devicemapper (loop) is not recommended for production use:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/